# Fatal error: Class 'Magentothem_Sale_Helper_Data' not found in /home/project/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento, helper, magento-1.8

I am struggling with one issue like - Fatal error: Class

> Magentothem_Sale_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home/project/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Here is the `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentothem_Sale>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentothem_Sale>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <sale>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentothem_Sale</module>
                    <frontName>sale</frontName>
                </args>
            </sale>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sale>
                    <file>sale.xml</file>
                </sale>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <sale>
                <class>Magentothem_Sale_Helper</class>
            </sale>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is the `Helper/Data.php` :-

```
class Magentothem_Sale_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Getting error - `Fatal error: Class 'Magentothem_Sale_Helper_Data' not found`. Not able to understand where i am doing wrong.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need check `compiler is enable or not`.

If yes then you need `to Disable and again enable the compiler` for put the `Data.php at compiler location`.

Also you need to check file permissions.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have forget to disable the compilation. Thanks a lot :)